# How to prevent background image out of shape in Android?

Tags: android

I have a background image which is 1280 X 720 that fits my S3 so much.
However, if I want to fit other devices, how to do it?
For example, if one device is 800 X 600, if I scale the image from 1280 X 720 to 800 X 600, the image will a little bit out of shape.
Also, I want the image to fit fullscreen size.
Is there any good idea?
After I research, I know that I should prepare different resolution images, but which resolutions should I prepare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an image that can be used as a 9-patch then I'd suggest something like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/backgroundimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This solution will give you an image that covers whole the screen. The image will be uniformly stretched but some parts will be cut out as it uses centerCrop.

Comment: so that it will "cut" some part to suit the screen?

Comment: @jjLin yes exactly. Its the only way to put an image that is too large or to small within a screen and make it fit without stretching the image non uniformly and to avoid blank space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 9patch graphics. Find draw9patch.bat in your Android/tools directory. You put your PNG file through this utility, and mark the areas of the graphic that can be stretched to fit the display.

Comment: Check out tutorial at developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: the image is photo, so I think 9patch is not suitable.